# Mysqli fetch being interrupted

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table with progressive numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 15, and others...)

With the following code, all of these numbers will be printed out correctly.

```
$mysqli->select_db("db");

    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `numbers` FROM `table`
    WHERE 1 LIMIT 0, 999999");

    $sql->execute();
    $sql->bind_result($pbx);

    while ($sql->fetch()){


        printf($pbx . "\n");
}
```

> Output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 15, ecc...

Unfortunately, I need to execute some other mysqli code inside of this fetch. Doing so, seems to interrupt the fetch itself as only the first iteration will work properly.

I'm posting the whole code inside the fetch here. Please tell me if you see something which may cause this to happen. I've commented out the part which blocks the fetch.

```
$mysqli->select_db("db");

    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `numbers` FROM `table`
    WHERE 1 LIMIT 0, 999999");

    $sql->execute();
    $sql->bind_result($pbx);

    while ($sql->fetch()){


        printf($pbx . "\n");

        /* // COMMENT OUT FROM HERE, AND THE FETCH WILL STOP
        $sql->store_result();

        $mysqli->select_db("asterisk");
        $sql = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `devices` VALUES
        (?, 'sip', ?, 'fixed', ?, ?, NULL)"
        );


        $dial = "SIP/" . $pbx;

        $sql->bind_param('ssss', $pbx, $dial, $pbx, $pbx);

        $sql->execute();


        $sql = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES
        (?, NULL, ?, 'novm', 0, NULL, 'out=Adhoc|in=Adhoc', NULL, ?, 'default')
        ");

        $sql->bind_param('sss', $pbx, $pbx, $pbx);
        $sql->execute();

        $sql = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `sip`
            VALUES (
            ?, 'account', ?, 0
            ), (
            ?, 'secret', '123', 0
            ), (
            ?, 'qualify', 'yes', 0
            ), (
            ?, 'type', 'friend', 0
            ), (
            ?, 'context', 'hotel', 0
            ), (
            ?, 'host', 'dynamic', 0
            ), (
            ?, 'nat', 'yes', 0
            ), (
            ?, 'port', '5060', 0
            )
        ");

        $sql->bind_param('sssssssss', $pbx, $pbx, $pbx, $pbx, $pbx, $pbx, $pbx, $pbx, $pbx);
        $sql->execute();
        */ // COMMENT END

    }
```

> Output: 1

Comment: You're re-setting `$sql` inside the loop. Rename the variable you're using for the second query, and see what happens.

Comment: Oh thanks! Will try to fix it now.

Comment: @andrewsi why don't you post this as an answer so that OP could accept it?

Comment: It works now, thanks again! If you post as an answer I'll accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop variable is being re-set inside your loop

```
while ($sql->fetch()){
    (...)
    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `devices` VALUES
        (?, 'sip', ?, 'fixed', ?, ?, NULL)"
        );
```

So when it gets to the end of the loop, the original contents of `$sql` have disappeared.

You just need to re-name either varaible, and the code should work.